# ggplot: generate a plot of coloured segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have `bands`, a data frame that contains the (date, y) coordinates of a set of lines.
The lines look as almost perfect horizontal lines.

```
                          entryL      entryH         exitL        exitH
11/06/2013 00:00:00 -0.011269079 0.011269079 -0.0005634540 0.0005634540
11/05/2013 00:00:00 -0.011247277 0.011247277 -0.0005623638 0.0005623638
11/04/2013 00:00:00 -0.011246974 0.011246974 -0.0005623487 0.0005623487
11/01/2013 00:00:00 -0.011239644 0.011239644 -0.0005619822 0.0005619822
10/31/2013 00:00:00 -0.011237719 0.011237719 -0.0005618859 0.0005618859
10/30/2013 00:00:00 -0.011236857 0.011236857 -0.0005618428 0.0005618428
10/29/2013 00:00:00 -0.011278355 0.011278355 -0.0005639178 0.0005639178
```

I have `posFrame`, a data frame that contains another line (`Spread`) and a marker column (`Positioning`), that defines the state of the system.

```
                    Positioning        Spread
11/06/2013 00:00:00        Idle -1.309504e-03
11/05/2013 00:00:00        Idle  2.517881e-03
11/04/2013 00:00:00        Idle  1.035712e-03
11/01/2013 00:00:00        Idle  6.470740e-03
10/31/2013 00:00:00        Idle  4.975187e-03
10/30/2013 00:00:00        Idle  3.655266e-03
10/29/2013 00:00:00        Idle -8.704032e-03
10/28/2013 00:00:00       Short  2.790278e-03
10/25/2013 00:00:00       Short  6.690602e-03
10/24/2013 00:00:00       Short  3.098176e-03
```

I would like to plot the two data frames together. This is my current attempt.

```
bands$time <- rownames(bands)
bands$time <- as.POSIXct(bands$time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") 
posFrame$time <- rownames(posFrame)
posFrame$time <- as.POSIXct(posFrame$time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")        
frame.m <- melt(frame, id = "time")
ggplot() +          
  geom_line(data = frame.m, aes (x = time, y = value, colour= variable)) +
  geom_jitter(data = posFrame, aes(x = time, y = Spread, colour = Positioning)) +
  geom_line(data = posFrame, aes(x = time, y = Spread)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=c(NA,16),linetype=c(1,0))))
```

[image]

The picture does not look good.
It would be great if I could plot the `Spread` line in colored segments where the color  matches the color of the previous marker diamond.

Furthermore, I do not understand why the legend mixes the diamond color, associated to `Positioning` and the solid line colors, associated with the bands.

I am not sure how I could proceed.. 
Thank you.

Comment: You could share your total _frame_ dataset, so your example will be reproducible.

Comment: you can't really map two independent variables to the same aesthetic